# create an excel file in C# with a file save dialog feature . The excel process will be keep running forever in the background

Tags: c#, excel

I am new to C#, working on a project recently. having problem about saving the excel file part. I want the user to be able to choose where to save the file (BTW, I don't want the file to be read-only). It is like file save dialog. I am using C# console .Net. I can save it to a specific location(with a path) now. Another problem, somehow, the excel file created by the program will be running forever in the background. Can anyone please help me? I have been working on this part for 2 days. Thank you so much.

Code:

```
 private static void excelFile(System.Data.DataTable dtTable,List<Dictionary<string, object>> list)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            Console.WriteLine(filepath);
            string filename = @"output1.xlsx";
            Console.WriteLine(filepath + filename);


      // Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkbook = null;
        var wkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        wkbook.SaveAs(ReadOnlyRecommended: false);    

       _Worksheet wksheet = wkbook.ActiveSheet;

             wksheet.Name = "APPLE";

        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dtTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                wksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dtTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            //rows
            for (var i = 0; i < dtTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < dtTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    wksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dtTable.Rows[i][j];
                }
            }           

            //System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);

            //File.SetAttributes(filename, ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            //File.SetAttributes(filename, ~FileAttributes.Hidden);

           //xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
           // wkbook.Save();
            //wkbook.Close();
            //xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Workbooks.Close();

            xlApp.Quit();

        }
        finally
        {
            if (wksheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wksheet);
            if (wkbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkbook);
            if (xlApp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please edit this question to split it into your two questions.  The first - how to get user input from a file save dialog, and the second is how to properly dispose of VSTO COM objects.  Actually, both of those have probably been answered.

Comment: There's no catch block - are you sure your code isn't erroring?

Comment: Yes, actually I have catch block in my code. Somehow I didn't post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The code below works.(ignore the catch block )

Code:

```
    private static void excelFile(System.Data.DataTable dtTable, List<Dictionary<string, object>> list)
    {
        // File save dialog
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (*.xls)|*.xls";

        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog.FileName = null;
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Save path of the file to be exported";

        //string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbooks wkbooks = null;
        Excel.Workbook wkbook = null;
        Excel.Sheets wksheets = null;
        Excel.Worksheet wksheet = null;

        try
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            wkbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            wkbook = wkbooks.Add();
            wksheets = wkbook.Sheets;
            wksheet = wksheets.Add();



            Console.WriteLine(list[0].Values);
            wksheet.Name = "APPLE";

            try
            {
            Console.WriteLine("It is working.");
            for (var i = 0; i < dtTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                wksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = dtTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            //rows
                for (var i = 0; i < dtTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (var j = 0; j < dtTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        wksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dtTable.Rows[i][j];
                    }
                }
            //wkbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8,false,
            //false, false,false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
            //Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                Console.WriteLine("Processing!");

                Console.WriteLine("File saved.");

                wkbooks.Close();
                wkbook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                xlApp.Quit();      

            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {

            }
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            if (wksheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wksheets);
            if (wkbook != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkbook);
            if (wkbooks != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wkbooks);
            if (xlApp != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
    }
}
```